# identityserver3 & MVC (web socket) & "websocket server" architecture

Tags: identityserver3

I want to implement identityserver3 Authentication & Authorization on MVC. And i'm using web sockets on MVC app. I have a self-hosted-web-socket-server (SHWSS). My client side web sockets communicate with my SHWSS. After successful login on identityserver how can I use these claims and tokens for websocket to SHWSS security.
I dont want my SHWSS answer to unauth requests.

I think It's somehow a SSO scenario. Which flow SHWSS must implement?

Thanks & Regards

```
public enum Flows
{
    AuthorizationCode = 0,  //introduced in OAuth2 then extended by OIDC.
    Implicit = 1,           //introduced in OAuth2 then extended by OIDC.
    Hybrid = 2,             //introduced in OIDC
    ClientCredentials = 3,  //OIDC specs didn't extend this flow.
    ResourceOwner = 4,      //OIDC specs didn't extend this flow.
    Custom = 5,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with web sockets is that the JS API does not allow setting custom request headers (like Authorization so you can pass a bearer token). I think the assumption is that you would use cookies as the authentication mechanism.

The other idea is to pass the access token as a custom param on every web socket request.

Comment: As I understand I can use cookies or send the access token as a parameter. :)
Should I confirm these with IdentityServer3 ? I mean should self-hosted-web-socket-server (SHWSS) app check these with Identity Server 3?
And is there an endpoint that I can do so, ie give me a reply that if this access token is logged.

Really appreciate your efforts, thanks

Comment: All in the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/introspection.html